# Keep incresing memory allocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

In my iOS app implemented for save videos from the web. It keeps increasing the memory usage when downloading videos. I have inspect using profile in xcode and saw some malloc getting increase per video.
[image]

[image]
I am not familiar with profile stuff. I have released the receivedData NSMUtableData variable.

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

   NSString *documentsDirectry = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
   NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"video_%@.mp4"),videoURL];
   [receivedData writeToFile:[documentsDirectry  stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename ] atomically:YES];
   receivedData = nil;
   [receivedData release];
   progress.hidden = YES;
```

}

App getting down its performance. How can i fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have **not** released receivedData. You have set the variable to nil before, so any message sent to receivedData goes to nirvana.

Also don't forget to handle cases when connectionDidFinishLoading is never called, you have to release it elsewhere too because of this.